# Angular2: How to get form validation status of page 1 on page 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm using Angular 4.2.x in the project, and it has 2 pages: page 1 has a form, and page 2 is a summary page.

Once all fields on page 1 are validated, I store a true flag in a service shared by both pages. I expect to display this flag when loading the page 2, however, it's always false although page 1 has marked this variable to be true.

Page1Component:

```
export class Page1Component implements OnInt {
   ngOnInit() {
      this.form1.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
         if (this.form1.invalid) {
           this.globalService.updatePageStatus(false);
         } else {
           this.globalService.updatePageStatus(true);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

GlobalService:

```
export class GlobalService {
   isPageCompleted: false;

   updatePageStatus(isCompleted: boolean) {
     this.isPageCompleted = isCompleted;
     console.log("Is page 1 completed? " + this.isPageCompleted);
   }
}
```

Page2Component:

```
export class Page2Component implements OnInit {
   isPage1Completed = false;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.isPage1Completed = this.globalService.isPageCompleted;
      console.log("On page 2, is page 1 completed? " + this.isPage1Completed);
   }
}
```

And Page1Component and Page2Component are in different modules which are lazy loaded. In browser console, I can see "**Is page 1 completed? true**", but when navigating to page 2, it shows "**On page 2, is page 1 completed? false**".

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have been creating separate instances of the services in both of your component ( using it in provider decorative property in both ).

Create only single instance ( using it in module rather than class as a provider ). this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 'GlobalService' as a singleton? If you import it in Page2Component it will create a new service rather then being a singleton, which will give you your default value for 'isPageCompleted' which is false.

Instead just import it in your module, rather than in the component.